# Source of where the day of Judgement will occur (Earth/heaven)

Tags: quran, hadith

I had from a scholar that before the day of judgement occur, the sun will be close to head of mankind and every mankind will be scared, before our beloved prophet will ask Allah to forgive his ummah and start the day of judgement.

So may question is, I had the scholar saying that Allah will reply the pray of our beloved prophet and said that **I will come and start the day of judgement**, so does that mean it will occur on this Earth and other
Please I want reference

Comment: The closest I could find is [this](https://sunnah.com/muslim/53/75) sahih hadith it covers the first part as it seems to me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Day of Judgement will occur on another "earth" that Allah will create replacing this Earth.

Allah says:

> [It will be] on the Day the earth will be replaced by another earth, and the heavens [as well], and all creatures will come out before Allah, the One, the Prevailing. (14:48)

Comment: Thanks for that answer